# Could not find or load main class, when running spring boot jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I Have issues running a jar that was created through 'mvn package'. I tried various solutions with no success.

pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
...
<properties>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
  <start-class>ves.sfdc.Application</start-class>
</properties>


<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

projectroot\src\main\java\ves\sfdc\application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class Application{

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;
    @Autowired
    static
    SfdcUtil sfdcUtil= new SfdcUtil();
    @Autowired
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate2;    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, IOException {   
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }        
}
```

This project works fine in Eclipse, and when I do **mvn spring-boot:run**

I Wonder if I'm missing something here?

Comment: Why are you using the maven-shade-plugin? Also, you should remove `<start-class>ves.sfdc.Application</start-class>`. Spring Boot and its maven plugin take care of it.

Comment: not sure. borrowed this from a guide when back when haha. I had errors mvn packaging removing the <start-class> though before? It couldn't find the main.

Comment: Remove the maven-shade-plugin as well. It's not needed for Spring Boot

Comment: removed both. but having issues mvn build. [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin
:1.4.4.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project gs-rest-service: Execution default
 of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.4.RELEASE:repacka
ge failed: Unable to find a single main class from the following candidates [ves
.sfdc.Application, ves.sfdc.util.SForceConnector] -> [Help 1]

Comment: Maybe my answer will help you.

Answer (score 6):

With Spring Boot you don't need the maven-shade-plugin. Spring Boot will take care of the necessary packaging.

If you have multiple classes with main methods, you can configure the spring-boot-maven-plugin with the correct one:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>ves.sfdc.Application</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can find a list of possible configurations in the documentation of the maven plugin: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html

Comment: for me I has shade plugin... got rid of it and works

Answer (score 3):

**The problem in this case is with maven .
The dependencies you have downloaded not having the required version.
Some dependencies work in bulk with each other and some times they only match up with particular version of other jars.**

> ```
> Solution:- It will take some time but clear .m2 and rebuild maven to download all dependencies again.
> or 
> you are having two version of same dependencies.
> So check all maven jars and remove jars having common names.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is the incorrect/improper dependency.
Found in *markers > problems* is highlighting 
**`.pom` is not valid archive.**

`compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcomponents-client', version: '4.5.6', ext: 'pom'`

Changed this to

```
    `compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.6'`
```