# maven-shade-plugin - Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-shade-plugin

I copied configuration of maven shade plugin straight from apache maven documentation https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html

This is my current set up:

```
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>com.my.app.MainClass</Main-Class>
                <X-Compile-Source-JDK>1.8</X-Compile-Source-JDK>
                <X-Compile-Target-JDK>1.8</X-Compile-Target-JDK>
              </manifestEntries>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.DontIncludeResourceTransformer">
                <resource>.properties</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
            </transformer>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
            </transformer>              
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And I'm getting following error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.0:shade (default) on project cpms-batch: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.0:shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.0:shade (default) on project cpms-batch: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.0:shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginConfigurationException: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.1.0:shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:662)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:594)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
>       ... 20 more
>   Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.ComponentConfigurationException: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.setProperty(CompositeBeanHelper.java:252)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:101)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.fromConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:57)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.AbstractCollectionConverter.fromChildren(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:54)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ArrayConverter.fromConfiguration(ArrayConverter.java:52)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.convertProperty(CompositeBeanHelper.java:273)
>       at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.CompositeBeanHelper.setProperty(CompositeBeanHelper.java:210)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.converters.composite.ObjectWithFieldsConverter.processConfiguration(ObjectWithFieldsConverter.java:101)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.component.configurator.BasicComponentConfigurator.configureComponent(BasicComponentConfigurator.java:34)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.populatePluginFields(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:632)
>       ... 23 more
>   [ERROR]

I've seen multiple questions regarding that error without the answer:
[shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43626806/shade-for-parameter-resource-cannot-find-resource-in-class-org-apache-maven-p)

[Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616259/cannot-find-resource-in-class-org-apache-maven-plugins-shade-resource-manifest)

Was anyone able to resolve it or found the reason?

Comment: Spring Boot does not require the Maven Shade Plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43613830/3810038

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This post resolved my issue:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/384

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It would be great to have an explanation.  The github post is old and explains nothing.  Having said that, this solution did fix my problem.

Answer (score 14):

It's going to sound stupid but you need **add** an **id and a phase** to your shade plugin configuration (I don't know why but it works)

```
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>shade-jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>shade</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <transformers>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
          <manifestEntries>
            <Main-Class>com.my.app.MainClass</Main-Class>
          </manifestEntries>
        </transformer>
      </transformers>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</executions>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, no idea why the Transformers documentation doesn't include this in their examples.

Comment: yes, after adding the id tag, it worked. i had already phase in my pom.xml

Comment: Thanks. In my case with Spring Boot 3.2.2 and therefore maven-shade-plugin 3.4.1, adding "id" was sufficient. Adding "phase" was not necessary.

Answer (score 11):

Spring Boot has its own maven-shade-plugin config. Add this property to your pom.xml:

```
<properties>
  <start-class>com.lionmint.core.test.integration.apns.mock.MockAPNSServer</start-class>
</properties>
```

Comment: This is a good answer cause not only this solved my issue I also got to navigate to `spring-boot-starter-parent-3.2.2.pom` file where I was able to understand what all properties are configurable and what all options are available out of the box and what all options are configurable. Thank you.