# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.3:shade

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to **dockerize my springboot application**, for which my `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/spring-boot-docker.jar spring-boot-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/spring-boot-docker.jar"]
```

After running `mvn clean` from the terminal, when I run `mvn install`, from the terminal, I get the below mentioned errors and the build failed

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.3:shade (default) on
>   project moviesearch: Unable to parse configuration of mojo
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.3:shade for parameter
>   resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class
>   org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer ->
>   [Help 1] [ERROR]

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!--jars-->
        <es.client.version>7.6.0</es.client.version>
        <!--plugin version-->
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.shade.version>3.2.3</maven.shade.version>
        <maven.checkstyle.version>3.1.1</maven.checkstyle.version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>2.6</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>moviesearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>moviesearch</name>
    <description>Movie search using Spring Boot</description>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
          <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
          <version>7.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
         </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>${es.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>${es.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.10.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.es.scanner.ScannerApplication</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.checkstyle.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
        <finalName>spring-boot-docker</finalName>

    </build>

</project>
```

The solution to this error is also provide in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49215416/maven-shade-plugin-cannot-find-resource-in-class-org-apache-maven-plugins-sh), but this did not work for me.

Can anyone help me resolve this issue ?

Comment: Remove all the plugins, leave only `spring-boot-maven-plugin` that already creates a jar suitable for docker. You are trying to mimic what that plugin does by doing all the stuff again (badly).

Comment: @M.Deinum thank u ! It worked for me, by removing all other plugins except ```spring-boot-maven-plugin```, the project was successfully build.

Comment: @M.Deinum can you please add a detailed answer with some links to explain how ```spring-boot-maven-plugin``` creates an executable  jar which is suitable for docker, so that I can mark it as an answer  ;-)